# db executeUpdate... in FMDB block and doesn't go over, without error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

i'm using the amazing FMDB project in my app in development, i have a NSOperation like this:

```
- (void)main
{
 @autoreleasepool {

FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"pathDB"]];

[queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

    FMResultSet *toQuery;

    if (self._id == nil) {
        toQuery = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT id,language,update_time FROM task"];

    while ([toQuery next]) {

        [myarray addObject:[toQuery resultDictionary]];

    }
}];

for (int i = 0; i<[myarray count]; i++){

...Do Something

[queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

FMResultSet *checkImgQuery = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT img_url,img_path FROM task WHERE id = ? AND language = ?",myTask.id ,myTask.lang];

while ([checkImgQuery next]) {

 if (![[checkImgQuery stringForColumn:@"img_url"] isEqualToString:myTask.img]) {
                                    NSData *my_img = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myTask.img]];

if (my_img != nil) {

NSError *er;

[my_img writeToFile:[checkImgQuery stringForColumn:@"img_path"] options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&er];

//In the line under here the code block, the app still running, but this operation doesn't
//go over this task

[db executeUpdate:@"UPDATE task SET img_url = ? WHERE id = ? AND language = ?",myTask.img,[NSNumber numberWithInt:myTask.id],[NSNumber numberWithInt:myTask.language];

NSLog(@"%@",[db lastErrorMessage]);
}
...Do Something
}
}
}
}];
}
}
```

The problem is in `[db executeUpdate:...]` that sometime works with no problem and sometime freeze and doesn't go over that line, the `NSLog` i have put there doesn't print anything, the app doesn't crash and continue working, but the thread is stuck there, if i shutdown the run of the app, and i restart it again the thread doesn't stop on the same task, but random on another, with no criteria, some time one works, and some time doesn't...anyone can help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple issues that leap out at me, one or more of which may be contributing to your problem:

1. I notice that you're creating a `FMDatabaseQueue` object locally. You should only have one `FMDatabaseQueue` object shared for the entire app (I put it in a singleton). The purpose of the database queue is to coordinate database interactions, and it can't reasonably do that if you're creating new `FMDatabaseQueue` objects all over the place.
2. I'd advise against having an `inDatabase` block in which you're synchronously downloading a bunch of images from the network.

   When you submit an `inDatabase` task, any `inDatabase` calls on other threads using the same `FMDatabaseQueue` (and they should use the same queue, or else you're defeating the purpose in having a queue in the first place) will not proceed until the one running in your operation does (or vice versa).

   When doing database interaction from multiple threads, coordinated by the `FMDatabaseQueue` serial queue, you really want to make sure that you "get in and get out" as quickly as possible. Don't embed potentially slow network calls in the middle of the `inDatabase` block, or else all other database interaction will be blocked until it finishes.

   So, do an `inDatabase` to identify the images that need to be downloaded, but that's it. Then outside of the `inDatabase` call, retrieve your images, and if you need to update image paths or the like, separate `inDatabase` call do to do that. But don't include anything slow and synchronous inside the `inDatabase` block.
3. I also notice that you're doing a `SELECT` on `task` table, keeping that `FMRecordSet` open, and then trying to update the same record. You want to open your record set, retrieve what you need, and close that recordset before you try to update the same record you retrieved in your recordset.

   Always close the `FMResultSet` before you try to do the `executeUpdate` that updates the same record.
4. A bit unrelated, but I might suggest you consider including `img_url` and `img_path` in your original `SELECT` statement, that way your array of dictionary entries will already have everything you need and it saves you from have to do that second `SELECT` at all.

---

If you're wondering what the `FMDatabaseQueue` singleton might look like, you might have a `DatabaseManager` singleton whose interface looks like:

```
//  DatabaseManager.h

@import Foundation;
@import SQLite3;

#import "FMDB.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface DatabaseManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) FMDatabaseQueue *queue;

@property (class, readonly, strong) DatabaseManager *sharedManager;

- (id)init __attribute__((unavailable("Use +[DatabaseManager sharedManager] instead")));
+ (id)new __attribute__((unavailable("Use +[DatabaseManager sharedManager] instead")));

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and the implementation might look like:

```
//  DatabaseManager.m

#import "DatabaseManager.h"

@implementation DatabaseManager

+ (DatabaseManager *)sharedManager {
    static id sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _queue = [[FMDatabaseQueue alloc] initWithPath:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"pathDB"]];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then, any code that needs to interact with the database can retrieve the queue like so:

```
FMDatabaseQueue *queue = DatabaseManager.sharedManager.queue;
```

Comment: thank you very very much for this complete answer, i will try all this suggestion that you write, i have another question, i already have in my app a Singleton, that manage the NSOperationQueue, and the request to the server, i have to put the FMDatabaseQueue in singleton i already have, or i can create a new singleton DatabaseManager?

Comment: @Piero Whatever makes most sense for your design. If this operation queue was just for database-related interactions, then adding this to that might be logical. But technically it doesn't matter: The key thing is to make sure you only have one `FMDatabaseQueue` object, regardless of how you implement it.

Comment: @Piero Yes you can more than one type of singleton (e.g. one for your operation queue, one for your `FMDatabaseQueue`, etc.).