# FMDB freeze application when running execute update query

Tags: ios, performance, swift, freeze, fmdb

I am using FMDatabaseQueue to have the ability work with fmdb using GCD.
But GCD does not help.

When I try to perform any execute update query several times in one moment I got freeze of application.

To improve the performance I done 
 - complex query to reduce the number of queries 
 - use begin and commit transaction 
 - use setShouldCacheStatements
 But NOTHING help

Here is some example of code
func complexQuery(sqlQuery: String) -> Bool {

```
var result = false
self.databaseQueue.inDatabase() { database in

    database.setShouldCacheStatements(true)
    database.beginTransaction()
    result = database.executeStatements(sqlQuery)
    database.commit()
}
```

Comment: perhaps you should `close` and `open` your `FMDatabase`. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18216818/1866077

Comment: Please clarify "I got freeze of application". Did the app completely deadlock? Or merely stall momentarily while doing many updates on another thread. Precisely how long are we talking about here? Also, how many updates are you doing in `sqlQuery`? Did `result` indicate successful completion?

Comment: I have "merely stall momentarily while doing many updates on another thread" freezes. It's near about 4000 updates in 3 queries. The result is successful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try call closeOpenResultSets on the FMDB instance just before the execute query